# Synchronising writes to io.MultiWriter in golang

Tags: go

I am working on an app that should be able to write to both a `bytes.Buffer` as well to `os.Stdout` / `os.Stderr`.

Therefore I am creating an

```golang
w := io.MultiWriter(myBuf, os.Stdout)
```

The writes will be from multiple `goroutines`.

To make at least my `bytes.Buffer` thread safe, I am wrapping it

```
type Buffer struct {
    buffer bytes.Buffer
    mutex  sync.Mutex
}

func (s *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    s.mutex.Lock()
    defer s.mutex.Unlock()
    return s.buffer.Write(p)
}

func (s *Buffer) String() string {
    s.mutex.Lock()
    defer s.mutex.Unlock()
    return s.buffer.String()
}
```

How can I achieve the same result with the standard error / output writes?

I thought about using `log` but it does not implement the `io.Writer` interface.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with stdout and stderr? Those are not a `bytes.Buffer`, but you could replace them with the locked buffer you have here.

Comment: I want the writes to `stdout` / `stderr` not to be intermixed, but rather syncrhonized.

Comment: Then the approach you have here would suffice. What exactly didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I achieve the same result with the standard error / output writes?

With a mutex, like you said.

> I thought about using log but it does not implement the io.Writer interface.

Interesting idea, since it locks itself, but you can do this with plain old `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr`, both of which implement `io.Writer`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

type LockedWriter struct {
    w io.Writer
    l sync.Mutex
}

func (lw *LockedWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    lw.l.Lock()
    defer lw.l.Unlock()
    return lw.w.Write(p)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var w = &LockedWriter{
        w: io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, os.Stderr),
    }
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            for j := 0; j < i; j++ {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "I am goroutine %d (%d/%d)\n", i, j, i)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

In this particular case, I couldn't reproduce any interpolated writes, but I think if the messages were long enough or the goroutines were doing more operations, I would.

Comment: Yes, you would need much longer lines to fill some system buffer to get the writes to interleave, ~24bytes is much smaller than any reasonable buffer. `log.Logger` contains a mutex for this same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help:

```
type StdoutType {
    stdout *File
    mutex sync.Mutex
}

func NewStdoutType() *StdoutType {
    return &StdoutType{
        stdout: os.Stdout,
    }
}

func (s *StdoutType) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    s.mutex.Lock()
    defer s.mutex.Unlock()
    return s.stdout.Write(p)
}
```

`StdoutType` is now `io.Writer` compatible

Comment: `os.Stdout` already implements `io.Writer`.  Otherwise this is fine, it's pretty much the same code as my answer - Write  wrapper with mutex handling

Comment: I fail to understand the purpose of this comment

Comment: "StdoutType is now io.Writer compatible" my point is that `os.Stdout` is already `io.Writer` compatible ("implements `io.Writer`).  I will grant though that I'm not entirely sure what the OP's question was .  They were already using a `Write()` wrapper for a `bytes.Buffer` but said they were using `io.MultiWriter`

Comment: Ah.. I had meant `StdoutType` and not `Stdout` was now compatible - coz the point was to create this new type which uses mutex for writes - which i am guessing is what OP wanted. But true - not entirely sure.